# Draw a point on a raster image from CLI?

Tags: drawing, imagemagick, command-line-interface

HOw do I draw a point on an image with ImageMagick (or some other linux CLI tool)? I tried:

```
convert tension_00.png -pointsize 100 -fill black -draw 'point 10,10' tension_001.png
```

I doesn't give error, but I can't find a point on the processed image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I solved it with pygames (that is from python script):

```
import pygame
img = pygame.image.load('tension_00.png')
pygame.draw.circle(img, (1, 1, 1), (600,600), 50) # Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0
pygame.image.save(img, 'test.png')
```